# RecyclerView in RecyclerView parent.notifyDataSetChanged loose position of child RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I develop a fragment using Horizontal RecyclerView in a Vertical RecyclerView (like Google Play Store).

When i notifyDataSetChanged from the parent RecyclerView, the child RecyclerView lose the position because the setAdapter is call in the onBindViewHolder I think. Also when i scroll to the 5th position in the first horizontal recyclerview if i scroll down and come back up i loose the 5th position.

I try to use RecyclerView.scrollToPosition() but that don't work.

So i think i have two solution :

- a way (by a method or setting) to keep the position of my child recycler view. (BEST SOLUTION)
- a way to set manually the recyclerview position to where it was before the refresh. (ELSE SOLUTION)

Here my Parent Adapter :

```
public class ProfilesCardViewListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfilesCardViewListAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AidodysProfile> sectionsList;
    private Context context;
    private boolean[] isShown;
    private ProfileCardViewItemAdapter itemAdapters[];

    public ProfilesCardViewListAdapter(ArrayList<AidodysProfile> sectionsList, Context context) {

        this.sectionsList = sectionsList;
        this.context = context;
        this.isShown = new boolean[sectionsList.size()];
        this.itemAdapters = new ProfileCardViewItemAdapter[sectionsList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionsList.size(); i++) {
            this.isShown[i] = true;
            this.itemAdapters[i] = new ProfileCardViewItemAdapter(sectionsList.get(i).getProfiles(), context, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_card_view_horizontal, null);
        final ItemRowHolder rowHolder = new ItemRowHolder(view);

        return rowHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemRowHolder holder, final int position) {
        String sectionName = sectionsList.get(position).getName();

        AidodysProfile[] sectionItems = sectionsList.get(position).getProfiles();

        holder.sectionTitle.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_profileslist_section_title));
        holder.sectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showHideSection(holder, position);
            }
        });

        if (isShown[position]) {
            holder.itemRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.sectionButton.setText(context.getString(R.string.action_profiles_section_hide));
        } else {
            holder.itemRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.sectionButton.setText(context.getText(R.string.action_profiles_section_show));
        }

        if (!sectionsList.get(position).isLeaf()) { // FOLDER
            if (sectionName.equals("")) {
                holder.sectionTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.sectionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.sectionTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.sectionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            holder.sectionTitle.setText(sectionName);
        } else { // PROFILE
            return;
        }

        holder.itemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapters[position]);

    }

    private void showHideSection(ItemRowHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.itemRecyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            isShown[position] = false;
            holder.itemRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.sectionButton.setText(context.getText(R.string.action_profiles_section_show));
        } else {
            isShown[position] = true;
            holder.itemRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.sectionButton.setText(context.getString(R.string.action_profiles_section_hide));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (sectionsList != null ? sectionsList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView sectionTitle;
        protected RecyclerView itemRecyclerView;
        protected Button sectionButton;

        public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.sectionTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.section_title);
            this.itemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_view);
            this.sectionButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.section_button);
        }

    }
}
```

Child Adapter :

```
class ProfileCardViewItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileCardViewItemAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {
    private AidodysProfile[] itemsList;
    private CurrentUser currentUser;
    private Context context;
    private int selectedPos = -1;
    private ProfilesCardViewListAdapter parent;

    public ProfileCardViewItemAdapter(AidodysProfile[] itemsList, Context context, ProfilesCardViewListAdapter parent) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.context = context;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.currentUser = CurrentUser.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_view_horizontal, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder rowHolder = new SingleItemRowHolder(view);
        return (rowHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SingleItemRowHolder holder, final int position) {
        AidodysProfile profile = itemsList[position];

        holder.itemCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectProfile(holder, position);
            }
        });

        if (profile.equals(currentUser.getProfile())) {
            selectedPos = position;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                holder.itemCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
            } else {
                holder.itemCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                holder.itemCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
            } else {
                holder.itemCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        }

        holder.itemTitle.setText(profile.getName());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.itemPicture.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sheet_smile_black_48dp));
            holder.button1.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_edit_black_24dp));
            holder.button2.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_look_profile));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                holder.itemTitle.setTextAppearance(R.style.Aidodys_Text_ProfilesList_Item);
                holder.itemPicture.setColorFilter(context.getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.topParts.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
            } else  {
                holder.itemTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.itemTitle.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_profileslist_item));
                holder.itemPicture.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.topParts.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
            }
        } else {
            holder.button1.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_edit_black_24dp));
            holder.button2.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_look_profile));
            holder.itemTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.itemTitle.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_profileslist_item));
            holder.itemPicture.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sheet_smile_black_48dp));
            holder.itemPicture.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.topParts.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
        }
    }

    private void selectProfile(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int position) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("Aidodys", 0).edit();
        editor.putString("profile", new Gson().toJson(itemsList[position]));
        editor.apply();
        currentUser.setProfile(itemsList[position]);
        parent.notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        ((RecyclerView)holder.itemCardView.getParent()).scrollToPosition(position);
        selectedPos = position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (itemsList != null ? itemsList.length : 0);
    }

    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView itemTitle;
        protected ImageView itemPicture;
        protected CardView itemCardView;
        protected ImageView button1;
        protected ImageView button2;
        protected LinearLayout topParts;

        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            this.itemPicture = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_picture);
            this.itemCardView = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_list_item);
            this.topParts = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_list_item_top_part);
            this.button1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_button_1);
            this.button2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_button_2);
        }
    }
}
```

If someone has a solution for me

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, i use the onTouchListener in the child recyclerView to set a scrollPosition (i don't use onScrollListener because this method is deprecated) i implement a getter to this field to get the scroll position from the parent RecyclerView and so at the end of the onBindViewHolder in the parent RecyclerView i call (child)RecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition).

And that's make the job

Parent RecyclerViewAdapter :

```
public class ProfilesCardViewListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfilesCardViewListAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {
    private ArrayList<AidodysProfile> sectionsList;
    private Context context;
    private boolean[] isShown;
    private ProfileCardViewItemAdapter itemAdapters[];

    public ProfilesCardViewListAdapter(ArrayList<AidodysProfile> sectionsList, Context context) {

        this.sectionsList = sectionsList;
        this.context = context;
        this.isShown = new boolean[sectionsList.size()];
        this.itemAdapters = new ProfileCardViewItemAdapter[sectionsList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < sectionsList.size(); i++) {
            this.isShown[i] = true;
            this.itemAdapters[i] = new ProfileCardViewItemAdapter(sectionsList.get(i).getProfiles(), context, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_card_view_horizontal, null);
        final ItemRowHolder rowHolder = new ItemRowHolder(view);
        rowHolder.itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(context, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
        return rowHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemRowHolder holder, final int position) {
        String sectionName = sectionsList.get(position).getName();

        AidodysProfile[] sectionItems = sectionsList.get(position).getProfiles();


        holder.sectionTitle.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_profileslist_section_title));
        holder.sectionButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showHideSection(holder, position);
            }
        });

        if (isShown[position]) {
            holder.itemRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.sectionButton.setText(context.getString(R.string.action_profiles_section_hide));
        } else {
            holder.itemRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.sectionButton.setText(context.getText(R.string.action_profiles_section_show));
        }

        if (!sectionsList.get(position).isLeaf()) { // FOLDER
            if (sectionName.equals("")) {
                holder.sectionTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                holder.sectionButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                holder.sectionTitle.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                holder.sectionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            holder.sectionTitle.setText(sectionName);
        } else { // PROFILE
            return;
        }

        holder.itemRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        holder.itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(itemAdapters[position]);
        holder.itemRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(itemAdapters[position].getScrollPos());
    }

    private void showHideSection(ItemRowHolder holder, int position) {
        if (holder.itemRecyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
            isShown[position] = false;
            holder.itemRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.sectionButton.setText(context.getText(R.string.action_profiles_section_show));
        } else {
            isShown[position] = true;
            holder.itemRecyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.sectionButton.setText(context.getString(R.string.action_profiles_section_hide));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (sectionsList != null ? sectionsList.size() : 0);
    }

    public class ItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView sectionTitle;
        protected RecyclerView itemRecyclerView;
        protected Button sectionButton;

        public ItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            this.sectionTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.section_title);
            this.itemRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_recycler_view);
            this.sectionButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.section_button);
        }

    }
}
```

Child RecyclerViewAdapter :

```
class ProfileCardViewItemAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileCardViewItemAdapter.SingleItemRowHolder> {
    private AidodysProfile[] itemsList;
    private CurrentUser currentUser;
    private Context context;
    private int scrollPos = 0;
    private ProfilesCardViewListAdapter parent;

    public int getScrollPos() {
        return scrollPos;
    }

    public ProfileCardViewItemAdapter(AidodysProfile[] itemsList, Context context, ProfilesCardViewListAdapter parent) {
        this.itemsList = itemsList;
        this.context = context;
        this.parent = parent;
        this.currentUser = CurrentUser.getInstance(context);
    }

    @Override
    public SingleItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_card_view_horizontal, null);
        SingleItemRowHolder rowHolder = new SingleItemRowHolder(view);
        return (rowHolder);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SingleItemRowHolder holder, final int position) {
        AidodysProfile profile = itemsList[position];

        holder.itemCardView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                scrollPos = position;
                return false;
            }
        });
        holder.itemCardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                selectProfile(holder, position);
            }
        });

        if (profile.getId() == currentUser.getProfile().getId()) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                holder.itemCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
            } else {
                holder.itemCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                holder.itemCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.white));
            } else {
                holder.itemCardView.setCardBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            }
        }

        holder.itemTitle.setText(profile.getName());

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            holder.itemPicture.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sheet_smile_black_48dp));
            holder.button1.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_edit_black_24dp));
            holder.button2.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_look_profile));
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                holder.itemTitle.setTextAppearance(R.style.Aidodys_Text_ProfilesList_Item);
                holder.itemPicture.setColorFilter(context.getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.topParts.setBackgroundColor(context.getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
            } else  {
                holder.itemTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.itemTitle.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_profileslist_item));
                holder.itemPicture.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
                holder.topParts.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
            }
        } else {
            holder.button1.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_edit_black_24dp));
            holder.button2.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_look_profile));
            holder.itemTitle.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.itemTitle.setTextSize(context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.text_size_profileslist_item));
            holder.itemPicture.setImageDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_sheet_smile_black_48dp));
            holder.itemPicture.setColorFilter(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            holder.topParts.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.aidodysRed));
        }
    }

    private void selectProfile(SingleItemRowHolder holder, int position) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = context.getSharedPreferences("Aidodys", 0).edit();
        editor.putString("profile", new Gson().toJson(itemsList[position]));
        editor.apply();
        currentUser.setProfile(itemsList[position]);
        parent.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return (itemsList != null ? itemsList.length : 0);
    }

    public class SingleItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        protected TextView itemTitle;
        protected ImageView itemPicture;
        protected CardView itemCardView;
        protected ImageView button1;
        protected ImageView button2;
        protected LinearLayout topParts;

        public SingleItemRowHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            this.itemTitle = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
            this.itemPicture = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_picture);
            this.itemCardView = (CardView)view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_list_item);
            this.topParts = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.card_view_list_item_top_part);
            this.button1 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_button_1);
            this.button2 = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.item_button_2);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Store x scroll offset in a SparseArray for position and restore when bind view holder.

```
public class ProfilesCardViewListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfilesCardViewListAdapter.ItemRowHolder> {

    private SparseIntArray sparseArray = new SparseIntArray();

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ItemRowHolder holder, final int position) {

        // Use srollBy for animate scrolling
        holder.itemRecyclerView.srollBy(sparseArray.get(position, 0), 0);
        // Or scrollTo for restore previous x offset
        //holder.itemRecyclerView.srollTo(sparseArray.get(position, 0), 0);

        holder.itemRecyclerView.setOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

           @Override
           public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
               sparseArray.put(position, dx);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I test, i just see a little mistake in your code, you use two time scrollBy (it will be scrollTo the second time)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I did not expect, that itemRecyclerView is not finished layouting yet

Comment: Do you have another idea ?

Comment: I haven't. I tried scroll with LinearLayoutManager but that didn't work

Comment: i find a solution with your idea

Comment: this the answer i had posted yesterday